# Heroku Flask-SocketIO Error __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_hostname

Tags: python, heroku, flask-socketio

I was working on a web app that uses `Flask-SocketsIO`. 
While trying to deploy the webapp on `heroku` I ran into this issue:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_hostname'
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug: [Github](https://github.com/asciimoo/searx/issues/120)

Heroku uses python-2.7.9 by default.

According to above link it is fixed but I think this bug still persists, atleast with heroku's python.

Till the time this bug is fixed a simple solution is degrading python to 2.7.8.
To do this in heroku, create a file called **runtime.txt** and type python-2.7.8 in it. Push the update to heroku.

This should fix the issue.

After doing this my app is working :) : http://mycodebuddy.herokuapp.com/